# Python - Jinja2 - loop with counts

Tags: python, jinja2

I am trying to loop through creating interface configurations for a switch based on a pre defined variable, I understand I can do this in Jinja but im not sure on how to begin to acheive it

my template is as below.
through my python script i will pass 2 values, the amount of switches and the amount of ports

so if there are three switches 24 port switches i will need it to create a config for ports g1/0/1 to g1/0/24, g2/0/1 to g2/0/24 and g3/0/1 to 24.

does this make sense? i need to count against the two figures until they meet the values set

Thanks
Alex

```
{% for %}
interface GigabitEthernet{{ SW }}/0/{{ Port }}
 switchport access vlan {{ DATAVLAN }}
 switchport mode access
 switchport voice vlan {{ VOICEVLAN }}
 switchport port-security maximum 2
 switchport port-security violation restrict
 switchport port-security aging time 1
 switchport port-security aging type inactivity
 switchport port-security
 spanning-tree portfast
 spanning-tree bpduguard enable
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive managed to achieve my result, i created an array dynamically that will list all the ports, then iterated over that array, it works perfectly. not sure if theres a better way but this is good for now

Thanks

Create array

```
    #create interface list
    intSwitchCount = int(row['SWITCHES'].strip())
    intPortCount = int(row['PORTS'].strip())
    intSW = 0
    intPort = 0
    lstPorts = []
    while intSW != intSwitchCount:
        intSW += 1
        while intPort != (intPortCount) :
            intPort += 1
            strPort = '%s/0/%s' % (str(intSW),str(intPort))
            lstPorts.extend([strPort])
        intPort = 0
```

template

```
{% for item in SWITCHPORTS %}
interface GigabitEthernet{{ item }}
 switchport access vlan {{ DATAVLAN }}
 switchport mode access
 switchport voice vlan {{ VOICEVLAN }}
 switchport port-security maximum 2
 switchport port-security violation restrict
 switchport port-security aging time 1
 switchport port-security aging type inactivity
 switchport port-security
 spanning-tree portfast
 spanning-tree bpduguard enable
{% endfor %}
```